# C# Regex.Replace number letter number

Tags: c#, regex

How do I replace the string

```
2X6X14 #2&BTR KD SPF MIRREX 1/2X5
```

with

```
2 x 6 x 14 #2&BTR KD SPF MIRREX 1/2 x 5
```

I want to replace "X" with " x " but only if it is surrounded by numbers, not if it is eg on the end of a word like MIRREX

Comment: Replace matches of `(?<=\d)x(?=\d)` with `' x '`, where `(?<=\d)` is a *positive lookbehind* and `(?=\d)` is a *positive lookahead*.

Comment: It seems clear enough to me. I've voted to re-open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An X with a digit either side:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d)X(?=\d)",  "$1 x ");
```

This finds a digit followed by X, followed by another digit. It captures the first digit into a group $1 that is used in the replacement of eg `2X -> 2 x` then moves into the next match

Or indeed as Cary commented (with the small typo of X/x), just using lookarounds:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\d)X(?=\d)",  " x ");
```

..similar idea - finds an X between two digits, neither of which are captured or prevent matching the next X, so it's a case of replacing the found X with " x "